# Triggers If statement syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in `MySQL` `PHP` `WAMP`, my trigger is created successfully without if statement, it gives error when I execute it error is  :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (NEW.userloc_lat ='91.000000' AND NEW.userloc_lan = '181.000000') THEN ' at line 6

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_new_userloc
    BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_userloc
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tbl_unknown_site
    IF (NEW.userloc_lat ='91.000000' AND NEW.userloc_lan = '181.000000')
    THEN SET 
    unknown_site_lat = NEW.userloc_lat,
    unknown_site_lon = NEW.userloc_lon,
    unknown_site_stt = NOW(),
    unknown_site_dtm = NEW.userloc_dtm,
    unknown_site_appid = NEW.userloc_appid,
    unknown_site_cellid = NEW.userloc_cellid,
    unknown_site_lacid = NEW.userloc_lacid,
    unknown_site_subid = NEW.userloc_id;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I think there would be only syntanx error what i am looking at.

Data type of `userloc_lat` and `userloc_lon` is `decimal(10,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` should be before `INSERT`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_new_userloc
    BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_userloc
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (NEW.userloc_lat ='91.000000' AND NEW.userloc_lon = '181.000000')
        THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_unknown_site
            SET 
                unknown_site_lat = NEW.userloc_lat,
                unknown_site_lon = NEW.userloc_lon,
                unknown_site_stt = NOW(),
                unknown_site_dtm = NEW.userloc_dtm,
                unknown_site_appid = NEW.userloc_appid,
                unknown_site_cellid = NEW.userloc_cellid,
                unknown_site_lacid = NEW.userloc_lacid,
                unknown_site_subid = NEW.userloc_id;
        END IF;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this gives error #1054 - Unknown column 'userloc_lan' in 'NEW', if i remove NEW from what you suggested it says during insert #1054 - Unknown column 'userloc_lat' in 'field list'. I think it not recognize it

Comment: You have a typo. `userloc_lan` should be `userloc_lon`.